# Create {forward-inverse-search} and make {forward-search} and {inverse-search} synonyms of it

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

The concepts of [forward-search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forward-search) and [inverse-search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inverse-search) are very closely related. Therefore I suggest to create a new [forward-inverse-search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forward-inverse-search) tag, make [forward-search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forward-search) (7 questions) and [inverse-search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inverse-search) (9 questions) synonyms of the new tag and merge the existing questions. (Note: 4 questions feature both tags at the moment, so the new tag would start with 12 questions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my suggestion has gained 9 upvotes so far, I ask a moderator to create [forward-inverse-search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forward-inverse-search) plus synonyms and to merge the existing questions.

Comment: Done as requested