# Make {synctex} a synonym of {forward-inverse-search}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

When asking my question about [creating a unified forward-inverse-search tag](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/create-forward-inverse-search-and-make-forward-search-and-inverse-search-s), I missed the fact that there is also a [synctex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synctex) tag. SyncTeX is a special technology for forward-inverse-searching, but I think it is appropriate to use the general tag for it. Therefore I suggest to make [synctex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synctex) a synonym of [forward-inverse-search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forward-inverse-search) and to merge the existing questions.

EDIT: As my proposal got some, but not too many upvotes, let my elaborate: I think that even if there were other techniques for forward-inverse-searching in (La)TeX than SyncTeX, the current [synctex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synctex) tag and the more general [forward-inverse-search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forward-inverse-search) are closely aligned, and the small number of overall questions does not warrant specialized tags (neither for SyncTeX nor for other techniques).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ask a moderator to make [synctex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synctex) a synonym of [forward-inverse-search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forward-inverse-search) and to merge the existing questions.